# I want to add 'download' and 'delete' options in a datatable of ASP.NET webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, datatable, webforms

Currently working on showing list of attachments in a datatable by consuming web-api.
Attachment details like "File_name" "File_Type" are all from API.

Now i want to add two more options to each row of that data table. "Download and Delete"

Below is my code for datatable from API.

Help needed to add delete and download options for each row.

This is an ASP.NET web page (.aspx).

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    
    string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Root data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
    
    
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();                    
    dt.Columns.Add("File Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("File Type");
    dt.Columns.Add("Uploaded Date");
    dt.Columns.Add("Delete");
    dt.Columns.Add("Download");

    foreach(var item in data.data)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(item.file_name,item.file_type,item.created_datetime);
        //dt.Rows.Remove(item.file_name);
    }
    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Classes with this project.

```
        {
            public string series { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string file_name { get; set; }
            public string file_type { get; set; }
            public DateTime created_datetime { get; set; }
            public string created_by { get; set; }
            public bool active { get; set; }
            public object updated_by { get; set; }
            public object updated_datetime { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public bool success { get; set; }
            public string message { get; set; }
            public List<ObjectOne> data { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Share your `Root` class

Comment: @FortyTwo added my classed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I "assume" that your GV now correctly displays the data?

So, keep in mind that the GV is NOT limited to the columns you display "from" the data source.

So, to the GV, you can add buttons, check box (say to select rows), and just about any other kind of control that will "repeat" for each given row.

Now, having stated the above?

To add/have/enjoy those extra columns (such as your download button, or delete button), then as a general rule, you want to change and "define" the markup for the GV.

In other words, we will make the assumption that the columns you plan to use are known ahead of time (however, clearly your code that creates the data table also assumes this, and thus I see little "issues".

Now, I don't have your data. And it not clear if your data has some path name to the files in question, or your download button will have to "consume" the file from the other system. Same goes for a "delete".

Are you looking to just "delete" the row from the given GV display, or an actual file delete is to occur? (with of course a update in the GV to reflect this.

So, lets assume I have a "list" of files in a collection of some sort.

So, like your code, we will create a table var, add the rows.

say like this:

```
        FileInfo[] MyFiles = MyDir.GetFiles("*.*");

        foreach (FileInfo MyFile in MyFiles)
        {

            MyTable.Rows.Add(MyFile.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString(),
                MyFile.Length.ToString(),MyFile.Name,MyFile.FullName);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = MyTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

(it really does not matter where the list came from, but ONLY that we do have that resulting table.

So, now comes the markup. That markup code as noted needs to include the columns you want (and you don't have to show nor include all columns from your dt either.

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    CssClass="table table-hover"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
    width="45%"
    >

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="File Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FullFile" HeaderText="Full File" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="File Size" HeaderText="Size" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <button id="cmdDownLoad" runat="server" 
                    class="btn myshadow" 
                    onserverclick="cmdDownLoad_ServerClick">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span>
                </button>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <button id="cmdDownLoad" runat="server" 
                    class="btn myshadow" 
                    onserverclick="cmdDownLoad_ServerClick">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And now we see/get this:

[image]

so, now the steps are to add a "event" click to each button, and have code behind "get/grab" the row you just clicked on, and then do whatever that button and code is supposed to do.

Ok, so here is the download button click.

```
protected void cmdDownLoad_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlButton btn= (HtmlButton)sender;
    GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

    string sFullFileName = gRow.Cells[2].Text;  // cells[0] - zero based

    // code here to do whatever


}
```

So, we can get/grab any information from that "row click" and do whatever we want based on that information in the gv.

Same goes for the delete button click.

Do note in the markup I used a "html button" in place of a asp.net button. But they work the SAME. Only reason for the html button is they allowed me to use the bootstrap icons.